# Unable to shake off hardcoded delay from my script

Tags: vba, excel, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I've written a script in vba in combination with selenium to parse all the company names available in a webpage. The webpage has got lazyloading method active so there are only 20 links become visible in each scroll. If I scroll 2 times then the number of links visible are 40 and so on. There are 1000 links available in that webpage. My below script can reach the bottom of that page handling all the scroll and fetch all the names available in that webpage.

However, it is necessary to wait a certain time after each scroll for that webpage to update the content. This is where I've used `hardcoded delay` but the process of hardcoding thing is very inconsistent and sometimes it makes the browser quit before the completion of the whole operation.

How can I modify this portion `.Wait 6000` to make it `Explicit Wait` instead of `Hardcoded Wait`.

This is what I've written so far:

```
Sub Getlinks()
    Dim driver As New ChromeDriver, prevlen&, curlen&
    Dim posts As Object, post As Object

    With driver
        .get "http://fortune.com/fortune500/list/"
        prevlen = .FindElementsByClass("company-title").Count

        Do
            prevlen = curlen
            .ExecuteScript ("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

            .Wait 6000  ''I like to kick out this hardcoded delay and use explicit wait in place

            Set posts = .FindElementsByClass("company-title")
            curlen = posts.Count
            If prevlen = curlen Then Exit Do
        Loop

        For Each post In posts
            R = R + 1: Cells(R, 1) = post.Text
        Next post
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you know if the browser becomes "busy" when it is loading this data? Depending on the method the website is using to get this data you may be able to use: Do While IeApp.busy Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 5, Now) Loop, Never mind, i didn't pay attention that you are using Chrome. not IE.

Comment: I did try what you suggested while playing the same using IE but that doesn't work at all. After one or two scroll the bowser quits very smoothly. Thanks for your suggestion by the way @Ricardo A.

Comment: Does it show any kind of a loader or waiting symbol? If so you should just wait for to exist and then disappear

Comment: Thanks @Tarun Lalwani for the hint. I tried that angle as well but could not make it successful. There is a whirling symbol visible after each scroll. The symbol becomes invisible as soon as the new items load. The symbol is within class `F500-spinner`.

Comment: I would go in chrome and int network tab load a slow network simulation profile. This will allow you enough time to view and get the spinner identifications and then later you should need to check the visibility and invisibility of the same

Comment: @Tarun Lalwani if you are using chrome then a good way to catch a 'spinner' is to open developer tools, go to sources tab, interact with browser to show spinner and then hit F8. This will pause the page and then you can examine the spinner in the console DOM more easily, even trying out selectors. It's a bit easier than slowing the network.

Comment: @elworthy, actually that is good point too. Recently while automating a site I had this issue that spinner was there not even for a second, so I had to slow down the network to make sure the API call it make is very slow :-) and then of course I could have used F8 afterwards

Comment: Your main goal is to get the 100 company names?

Comment: No, my main goal is to make the browser reach the bottom of that webpage without using hardcoded delay @krish KM.

Comment: @Topto If your after the data: The page somehow needs to load that data to inject it and this leads you to this request http://fortune.com/api/v2/list/2358051/expand/item/ranking/asc/0/10 (network tab in your browser developper tools) which returns a JSON that holds all the data per item inside list-items. You can modify this like http://fortune.com/api/v2/list/2358051/expand/item/ranking/asc/10/20 etc. It looks like the maximum items returned is 100 so http://fortune.com/api/v2/list/2358051/expand/item/ranking/asc/0/99 - http://fortune.com/api/v2/list/2358051/expand/item/ranking/asc/100/199 .

Comment: If I were after the data I didn't need to create this post at all cause you know the script I've pasted above can fetch it very smoothly @Hubisan . The only thing I wished to learn is any method which can lead me parse those items without using hradcoded delay. However, all it is I wanna learn is the design. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a **timeout** (specified period of time that will be allowed to elapse) to get rid of the hardcoded delay. The timeout needs to be hardcoded.

The differences between this and your original code are:

- The loop itself is running over and over (doesn't wait 6 s on each iteration) and checks for new content until new content is found or the timeout is reached.
- If the lazy loading takes more time than expected for instance when loading number 21 to 50 the loop "waits" and tries to get new content for the maximum time defined in timeout.
- Downside: On the last step when all content is loaded the loop will take as many seconds as the timeout is set to.

Code:

```
Sub Getlinks()
    Dim driver As New ChromeDriver, prevlen&, curlen&
    Dim posts As Object, post As Object
    Dim timeout As Integer, startTime As Double

    timeout = 10 ' set the timeout to 10 seconds

    With driver
        .get "http://fortune.com/fortune500/list/"
        prevlen = .FindElementsByClass("company-title").Count

        startTime = Timer ' set the initial starting time

        Do
            .ExecuteScript ("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
            Set posts = .FindElementsByClass("company-title")
            curlen = posts.Count
            If curlen > prevlen Then
                startTime = Timer ' reset start time if new elements found
                prevlen = curlen ' set new prevlen
            End If
        Loop While Round(Timer - startTime, 2) <= timeout ' check if timeout is reached

        For Each post In posts
            R = R + 1: Cells(R, 1) = post.Text
        Next post
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your efficient solution @Hubisan. It works as I desired. However, let's wait few more times, if anything more refined come along.

Comment: I have quoted you in another answer +1

Answer (score 4):

Here is a completely different approach that doesn't require using a browser, instead it submits a series of web requests. With this approach, waiting for a page to load isn't a concern.

Typically, with lazy loading pages, it will submit a new request to load up the data for the page as you scroll. If you monitor the web traffic you can spot the requests made and emulate those, I have done that below.

The result should be a list of company names, in ascending order in whatever the first sheet of Excel is.

**Things you'll need:**

*Add References to:*

- Microsoft Scripting Runtime
- Microsoft XML v6.0
- Add the VBA-JSON code to your project. You can find that [here](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON)

**Edit**

Changed the code to keep pulling data from the site, until there is no more items in the list. Thanks @Qharr for pointing this out.

**Code**

---

```
Public Sub SubmitRequest()
    Const baseURL As String = "http://fortune.com/api/v2/list/2358051/expand/item/ranking/asc/"

    Dim Url            As String
    Dim startingNumber As Long
    Dim j              As Long
    Dim getRequest     As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Dim Json           As Object
    Dim Companies      As Object
    Dim Company        As Variant
    Dim CompanyArray   As Variant

    'Create an array to hold each company
    ReDim CompanyArray(0 To 50000)
    'Create a new XMLHTTP object so we can place a get request
    Set getRequest = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60

    'The api seems to only support returning 100 records at a time
    'So do in batches of 100
    Do
        'Build the url, the format is something like
        '0/100, where 0 is the starting position, and 100 is the ending position
        Url = baseURL & startingNumber & "/" & startingNumber + 100

        With getRequest
            .Open "GET", Url
            .send

            'The response is a JSON object, for this code to work -
            'You'll need this code https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON
            'What is returned is a dictionary
            Set Json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(.responseText)
            Set Companies = Json("list-items")

            'Keep checking in batches of 100 until there are no more
            If Companies.Count = 0 Then Exit Do

            'Iterate the dictionary and return the title (which is the name)
            For Each Company In Companies
                CompanyArray(j) = Company("title")
                j = j + 1
            Next

        End With
        startingNumber = startingNumber + 100
   Loop

    ReDim Preserve CompanyArray(j - 1)

    'Dump the data to the first sheet
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1:A" & j) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(CompanyArray)

End Sub
```

---

Comment: Interesting approach. Is there anyway to determine the end point for looping so all is loaded? I commented at the top that this appears to be fixed for this website at 1000 which can also be scraped from the option 3 rank change. +1

Comment: Updated the code to keep checking until there are no more items

Comment: Faster, easier, more reliable, feasible, adaptable. +1

Answer (score 3):

There you go:

```
Sub Getlinks()
    Dim driver As New ChromeDriver
    Dim pcount As Long, R as long
    Dim posts As Object, post As Object

    With driver
        .get "http://fortune.com/fortune500/list/"
        Do
            .ExecuteScript ("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
            Set posts = .FindElementsByClass("company-title")
            pcount = posts.Count
        Loop Until pcount = 1000

        For Each post In posts
            R = R + 1: Cells(R, 1) = post.Text
        Next post
    End With
End Sub
```

Or even better, print as you go:

```
Sub Getlinksasyougo()
    Dim driver As New ChromeDriver
    Dim pcount As Long, R As Long, i As Long
    Dim posts As Object, post As Object


    With driver
        .get "http://fortune.com/fortune500/list/"
        i = 1
        Do
            .ExecuteScript ("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
            Set posts = .FindElementsByClass("company-title")
            pcount = posts.Count
            If i <> pcount Then
                For R = i To pcount - 1
                    Cells(R, 1) = posts(R + 1).Text
                Next R
                i = pcount
            End If
        Loop Until pcount = 1000

    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This is so far the best approach I could come across. The only thing it is necessary to shake off is this `pcount = 1000` hardcoded portion cause I may not be aware how many names are there. Provided plus one. Thanks.

Comment: This seems to be sufficient as that is 500 and 1000 but I guess you could scrape the 1000 with  Split(.FindElementsByTag("option")(3).Value, "rankchange")(1) I guess you are looking for a more transferable method for dealing with lazy loading pages.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to approach it using the "look for the spinner element" method discussed in one of the comments, which helps you avoid having to specify the number of elements you're expecting the page to load. The class name of the spinner actually changes depending on whether or not it's visible, which makes it pretty easy to just wait for the spinner to become visible + disappear again before getting the page elements.

This method still involves some waiting; by default, it waits 1/10th of a second after each attempt to find the spinner, either until the spinner is found or for some maximum number of attempts. But that's much faster than waiting 5 seconds every time.

Also, unrelated, but don't write stuff to cells one at a time, it's really slow. It's much faster to write it to an array first + write the entire array at once.

```
Sub getLinks()

    Dim bot As New ChromeDriver
    bot.Get "http://fortune.com/fortune500/list/"

    Dim posts As WebElements
    Dim numPosts As Long
    Dim finishedScrolling As Boolean
    finishedScrolling = False
    Do Until finishedScrolling
        'Set beginning post count and scroll down
        Dim startPosts As Long
        startPosts = numPosts
        bot.ExecuteScript "window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);"

        'Wait for spinner to become visible, then wait for up to 5 seconds for rehide
        Call waitForElements(bot, "div[class^='F500-spinner  ']", 50)
        Call waitForElements(bot, "div[class^='F500-spinner hide']", 50)

        'See if any new posts have loaded
        Set posts = bot.FindElementsByClass("company-title")
        numPosts = posts.Count
        If numPosts = startPosts Then
            finishedScrolling = True
        End If
    Loop

    'Write text to results array
    Dim post As WebElement
    ReDim resultsArr(1 To posts.Count, 1 To 1) As String
    Dim i As Long
    i = 1
    For Each post In posts
        resultsArr(i, 1) = post.Text
        i = i + 1
    Next

    'Write array to sheet
    With ActiveSheet
        .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(UBound(resultsArr, 1), 1)).Value = resultsArr
    End With

End Sub
Sub waitForElements(bot As WebDriver, css As String, maxAttempts As Long, Optional waitTimeMS As Long = 100)
'Use a CSS selector string to wait for element(s) to appear on a page or to reach max number of attempts
'By default, bot waits 0.1 second after each attempt

    Dim i As Long
    Dim foundElem As Boolean
    foundElem = False
    Do Until foundElem
        i = i + 1
        If bot.FindElementsByCss(css).Count > 0 Then
            foundElem = True
        ElseIf i = maxAttempts Then
            foundElem = True
        Else
            bot.Wait waitTimeMS
        End If
    Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will help as it's still a 'hard-coded' solution but you could try a delay function rather than the wait function and see if that helps with the program exiting issue.

```
Function Delay(Seconds As Single)
    Dim StopTime As Single: StopTime = Timer + Seconds
    Do While Timer < StopTime
        DoEvents
    Loop
End Function
```

Comment: You should show the usage of it within the script for better response. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are almost there.

Although I don't think you can avoid waiting, the work around is to keep a number of times checking for new posts as you scroll down with a shorter wait.

Example below is to check for new posts 5 times each with 2 seconds wait, so a total of 10 seconds before declaring end of the page. Adjust these 2 parameters to suit.

```
Sub Getlinks()
    Dim driver As New ChromeDriver, prevlen&, curlen&
    Dim posts As Object, post As Object
    ' Counter for number of times when there are NO NEW POSTS
    Dim NoIncreaseCount As Integer
    Const MaxNoIncreaseCount As Integer = 5
    Const WaitTime As Integer = 2000 ' 2 seconds wait time each scroll down

    With driver
        .get "http://fortune.com/fortune500/list/"
        prevlen = .FindElementsByClass("company-title").Count
        NoIncreaseCount = 0
        Do Until NoIncreaseCount = MaxNoIncreaseCount
            .ExecuteScript ("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
            .Wait WaitTime
            Set posts = .FindElementsByClass("company-title")
            curlen = posts.Count
            If prevlen < curlen Then
                ' There are new Posts
                prevlen = curlen
                NoIncreaseCount = 0
            Else
                ' No new Posts
                NoIncreaseCount = NoIncreaseCount + 1
            End If
        Loop

        For Each post In posts
            R = R + 1: Cells(R, 1) = post.Text
        Next post
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason for checking it for 5 times in 2 seconds intervals? The question is to how to get rid of hardcoded delay. What happens if the page loads 2.1 seconds later? The code will wait another 2 seconds which makes it 4 seconds instead of 2.1 seconds. What happens if page loads 10.1 secs later? That's also a possibility.

Comment: No particular reason. How many times to wait intervals really depends on the target website. You can put wait time to 1 sec and increase the max count base on your experience. Since you only want to get the text, you may want to customise the browser to disable multimedia loading (pics and vids) with ad blocking, even only allow script to run on main domain (3rd party scripts disabled).