# Parsing website that doesnt fully load VBA

Tags: vba, parsing

Trying my hand at a simple web parse, my problem is the page doesnt fully load until you scroll down. Google search has come up with possibly using selenium but as I have no idea how to use it I figured I would ask here

Code im using

```
Sub gfquote()

Dim oHttp As MSXML2.XMLHTTP
Dim sURL As String
Dim HTMLDoc As HTMLDocument
Dim dequote As String
Dim driver As New Webd
' Create an XMLHTTP object
Set oHttp = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP
    Dim oElement As Object
' get the URL to open
sURL = "https://www.thevinylspectrum.com/siser-heat-transfer-vinyl/siser-easyweed/12in-x-59in-rolls/"

' open socket and get website html
oHttp.Open "GET", sURL, False
oHttp.send
Set HTMLDoc = New HTMLDocument
With HTMLDoc
    ' assign the returned text to a HTML document
    .body.innerHTML = oHttp.responseText
    dastring = oHttp.responseText
    ' parse the result
  UserForm1.TextBox1.Text = dastring


   Set prices = .getElementsByClassName("price product-price")
    For Each oElement In prices
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i + 1) = prices(i).innerText
    i = i + 1
Next oElement



End With

'Clean up
Set oHttp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [selenium basic](http://florentbr.github.io/SeleniumBasic/) and using the technique by [@Hubisan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50510657/6241235) to handle lazy loading pages and scrolling until everything loaded:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetNamesAndPrices()
    Dim driver As New ChromeDriver, prevlen As Long, curlen As Long
    Dim prices As Object, price As Object, name As Object, names As Object
    Dim timeout As Long, startTime As Double

    timeout = 10                                 ' set the timeout to 10 seconds

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With driver
        .get "https://www.thevinylspectrum.com/siser-heat-transfer-vinyl/siser-easyweed/12in-x-59in-rolls/"
        prevlen = .FindElementsByCss(".price.product-price").Count

        startTime = Timer                        ' set the initial starting time

        Do
            .ExecuteScript ("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
            Set prices = .FindElementsByCss(".price.product-price")
            Set names = .FindElementsByCss(".product-name")
            curlen = prices.Count
            If curlen > prevlen Then
                startTime = Timer
                prevlen = curlen
            End If
        Loop While Round(Timer - startTime, 2) <= timeout

        Dim r As Long
        With ActiveSheet
            For Each name In names
                r = r + 1: .Cells(r, 1) = name.Text
            Next
            r = 0
            For Each price In prices
                r = r + 1: .Cells(r, 2) = price.Text
            Next
        End With
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Some example output:

[image: Example output]

Comment: It perfectly does the job. Few months back I used to think handling lazyload in vba might not be possible (in an efficient manner). However, it is doing great nowadays exceeding the expectation in most of the cases.

Comment: @SIM I wasn’t sure if I should also credit you. I remember you sent me a link to a script where you did the above as well! I am happy to add in and add a link to that script (it was different site though)

Comment: It also has the “feel” of some of your coding style.

Comment: I made the comment because it feels good to see what is possible in python can also be possible in vba (most of the cases). Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for the help! when i run it, chrome opens up and has "data;" in the address bar, and then vba gives me a runtime error '0' automation error the operation completed successfully. and nothing else happens. It never goes past the .get in the code

Comment: Can it open any page e.g. driver.get "https://www.google.co.uk/" ? Also, do you have any security restrictions that might impact on automated browsers? I am guessing not if you were able to install selenium basic.

Comment: Fixed my issue, chromedriver was outdated. downloaded new driver and all is good. thank you again!